# How add percentage value in piechart?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, mschart

This is the code which i used to generate pie chart . I need to add percentage value to piechart series.Tries few ways but did not find solution.I have attached my working code output image and expected image .

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Collections;
 public bool GetPieChart(string XML , string Path)
    {
        try
        {
        // create chart instance
        var chart = new Chart();



        // set chart height and width
        chart.Height = 500;
        chart.Width = 600;

        // Add legend to chart
        chart.Legends.Add(new Legend() { Name = "Legend" });
        chart.Legends[0].Font = new Font("Verdana", 10);
        chart.Legends[0].Docking = Docking.Bottom;

        ArrayList xAxisData = new ArrayList();

        ArrayList yAxisData = new ArrayList();

        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(XML);

        XmlNodeList multiLine = xml.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/Report/PieChart/series");

        // Set Chart Title
        string title = xml.SelectSingleNode("/Report").Attributes["Name"].Value.ToString();
        chart.Titles.Add(title);
        chart.Titles[0].Font = new Font("Verdana", 12);

        // Set chart properties
        var chartArea = new ChartArea();
        chart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);

        Series series;

        // Add data to the chart

        foreach (XmlNode seriesNode in multiLine)
        {
            xAxisData.Clear();

            yAxisData.Clear();

            series = new Series();

            string seriesName = seriesNode.Attributes["name"].Value.ToString();


            XmlNodeList detailsList = seriesNode.SelectNodes("datapoint");

            foreach (XmlNode detailNode in detailsList)
            {
                xAxisData.Add(detailNode.Attributes["Label"].Value.ToString());

                int value;

                string st = detailNode.Attributes["value"].Value.ToString();

                int.TryParse(st, out value);

                yAxisData.Add(value);
            }

            // set series properties
            series.Name = seriesName;
            series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;

            chart.Series.Add(series);
            chart.Series[seriesName].Points.DataBindXY(xAxisData, yAxisData);
            chart.Series[seriesName]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Outside";
            chart.Series[seriesName]["PieLineColor"] = "Black";
        }

        chart.SaveImage(Path, ChartImageFormat.Jpeg);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        return true;
    }
```

This is the out put from this code

[image]

This is what i expect

[image]

Guys need your help to do that ?

Answer (score 5):

```
foreach (DataPoint p in YourChart.Series["YourSeriesName"].Points)
        {
            p.Label = "#PERCENT\n#VALX";
        }
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question unless you provide some explanation.

Comment: for every series in pie chart you add percentage value

Comment: The add that explanation *to the answer*.

Answer (score 4):

Finally found solution. Now works well.

```
            chart.Series[seriesName].XValueMember = "Name";
            chart.Series[seriesName].YValueMembers = "Count";
            chart.Series[seriesName].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

escape percentage sign with double percentage char. look for the sample below

```
Chart1.Series.Add(series);

Series series1 = Chart1.Series[0];
series1.Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues);

Title ti = new Title()
ti.TextStyle = TextStyle.Emboss;
ti.Text = ((yValues[0] / 100) * 100) + @"%%";//double Percentage sign 
ti.Font = new Font("Times New Roman", 40, FontStyle.Bold);     
ti.Position.X = 50;
ti.Position.Y = 50;

Chart1.Titles.Add(ti);
```

Comment: what is `ti`? And it looks like you're adding the label as a title, why that?

Comment: @DdW I think ti must be last point added to the series = series1.Points.Last()

Comment: my point was that it is not declared in the code snippet. For people new to charts it's quite important information to have.

Answer (score 2):

this maybe help. This code is for a Pie Chart with percentage inside the Pie and labels(strings) in the legends: Where datosSeries = List

```
        string[] labels = datosSeries.Select(o => o.Week).ToArray();
        float[] data = datosSeries.Select(o => o.ProfitSerie).ToArray();
        chart2.Series.Add("Series1");
        chart2.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(labels, data);
        chart2.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
        chart2.Series[0]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Outside";
        chart2.Series[0].BorderWidth = 1;
        chart2.Series[0].BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(26, 59, 105);
        chart2.Series[0].Label = "#PERCENT{P2}";

        chart2.Legends.Add(new Legend("Default"));
        // Add Color column
        LegendCellColumn firstColumn = new LegendCellColumn();
        firstColumn.ColumnType = LegendCellColumnType.SeriesSymbol;
        firstColumn.HeaderText = "";
        chart2.Legends["Default"].CellColumns.Add(firstColumn);
        // Add name cell column
        LegendCellColumn percentColumn = new LegendCellColumn();
        percentColumn.Text = "#VALX";
        percentColumn.HeaderText = "Tipo de Gastos";
        percentColumn.Name = "nameColumn";
        chart2.Legends["Default"].CellColumns.Add(percentColumn);
        //Format the legend
        chart2.Legends["Default"].LegendStyle = LegendStyle.Table;
        chart2.Legends["Default"].TableStyle = LegendTableStyle.Tall;
        chart2.Legends["Default"].DockedToChartArea = "ChartArea1";
        chart2.Legends["Default"].IsDockedInsideChartArea = false;
        chart2.Legends["Default"].Docking = Docking.Bottom;
```